# My creature mixes lye and sal ammoniac to cool its blood. How cold can its blood get before it stops working as blood?

Tags: creature-design, chemistry, biochemistry, blood, endothermic-reaction

Background information:

- According to various sources, the human heart pumps [5 liters of blood/minute at rest and 15-20 liters of blood/minute during running or exercise](https://www.webmd.com/heart/heart-cardiac-output), [6,000 to 7,500 liters of blood/day (which is equal to 4⅙ to  5 5/24 liters of blood/minute)](https://www.smm.org/heart/lessons/lesson2.htm), [4.73 to 6.62 liters of blood/minute](https://hypertextbook.com/facts/2001/VitaliyShchupak.shtml), and so on and so forth. As such, 5 liters of blood/minute seems a reasonable placeholder value in regards to flow rate through the heart for the purposes of this question.
- According to various sources, the [specific heat capacity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Specific_heat_capacity) of blood is [3.49](https://www.zuniv.net/physiology/book/chapter21.html), [3.5](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/44493/which-is-the-specific-heat-of-human-body), or [3.617](https://itis.swiss/virtual-population/tissue-properties/database/heat-capacity/) kilojoules per kilogram per degree Celsius increase in temperature. I'll use 3.5 KJ/KG/C for the purposes of this question.
- There are more sources than I can list in regards to the density of blood, but most agree that it's roughly 1,025 to 1,060 kilograms per cubic meter.

  ```
  5 liters blood pumped/minute = 0.005 m^3 blood pumped/minute. 

  0.005 m^3 blood pumped/minute * 1,060 KG/m^3 blood 
  density = 5.3 KG blood pumped/minute. 

  5.3 KG blood pumped/minute * 3.5 KJ/KG/C = 18.55 KJ required to 
  cool 5.3 KG blood by 1 degree C.
  ```

[According to chemistry-reference.com](http://chemistry-reference.com/reaction.asp?rxnnum=492&func=stoich), there's a chemical reaction that uses up a [mole](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mole_(unit)) of [ammonium chloride/sal ammoniac](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ammonium_chloride), a mole of [lye/sodium hydroxide](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sodium_hydroxide), and 30.56 kilojoules of energy to produce a mole of water, a mole of [salt/sodium chloride](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sodium_chloride), and a mole of [ammonia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ammonia). In other words, I only need a single mole each of lye and ammonium chloride to cool *more* than a minute's worth of pumped blood by 1 degree Celsius - as a matter of fact, we can probably cool the blood as much as we want, since the reaction really doesn't need much of this stuff in order to function - the primary problem is venting the ammonia waste product.

A creature I'm working on takes advantage of this. Right before its blood vessels feed into its heart, a web of them - [a rete mirabile](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rete_mirabile), or, in technical terms, [a cooling jacket](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Batch_reactor#Single_external_jacket) - wraps around a biological [chemical reactor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chemical_reactor) within the creature's body, which is where this reaction occurs. When physically exerting itself, it triggers a valve in that chamber (*a la* a [bombardier beetle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bombardier_beetle)'s chemical-mixing mechanism), carries out the above chemical reaction, vents the resultant ammonia - which it can regenerate later - to the atmosphere, stores the salt in some kind of special receptacle, and pees the water out later. In exchange, the creature's blood gets heat sucked out of it, thereby reducing the rate at which it overheats.

**The question: how cold can this creature make its own blood before said blood stops working?** After all, as I said above, the blood can be cooled as much as I want; the unknown variable here is *how* much it can be cooled before bad stuff starts happening.

I recognize that [the viscosity of blood increases as its temperature decreases](https://academic.oup.com/ajh/article/14/5/433/205476), meaning that low-temperature blood is harder to pump, but that's not really the problem here since, after getting the heat pulled out of it, the blood will rapidly begin picking up more heat and its temperature will increase again. However, is there a temperature at which [red blood cells](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Red_blood_cell) can no longer carry oxygen, or at which they freeze so much that they can't function again - i.e. where it doesn't matter how much they get re-heated, because the sudden drop in temperature irreparably destroyed them? I'm currently thinking that that's somewhere between "freezing" and "normal body temperatures".

**Don't worry about anything else related to this creature's rather unique biology** - i.e. how it produces/stores ammonium chloride and lye or vents ammonia. That's not what this question is about. Moreover, **this creature is, for all other aspects - including the makeup of and chemical structure of its blood - a relatively normal human being**.

Inspired by [Gilgamesh's answer](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/a/219135/87100) to [this question of mine](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/219040/how-do-i-stop-bob-the-gigantic-animal-from-overheating).

Comment: I tried Google on "temperature hemoglobin". Lowest experimental temperature on life laboratory animals I can find for hemoglobine/oxigen functionality is 13.7 degrees Celcius. A rise of temperature from this hypotheric condition may be problematic, so the temperature is preferred to remain constant, not variable. The source may be interesting for you, I don't have the expertise for a good interpretation, so this is no answer, only a link https://www.frontiersin.org/articles/10.3389/fmed.2021.808025/full

Comment: @Goodies Thanks - reading through that now.

Comment: I don't think the correct number is 4 1/6 to 5 5/24 liters. I think it's only 4 1/5 to 5 4/24 litres.

Comment: @Daron 6,000 liters per day / 24 hours per day / 60 minutes per hour = 4.166666667 liters/minute, or 4 1/6 liters/minute.

Comment: @KEY_ABRADE Where does the bigger number come from?

Comment: @Daron The upper end of the range they gave was 7,500 liters per day, which equates to 7,500 liters per day / 24 hours per day / 60 minutes per hour = 5.208333333 liters/minute, or 5 5/24 liters per minute. The lower end of the range they gave was 6,000 liters per day, which gets 4 1/6 liters per minute. It's towards the end of that page.

Comment: @KEY_ABRADE Okay cool. It is confusing when you give the first figure (5 litres/minute or 7200/day) and then some conflicting figures (6000-7500 litres/day) and then a third figure  (4⅙ to 5 5/24 litres per minute) which is actually the second figure rephrased. It might be easier to read if you just use one figure.

Comment: Why is it storing the salt and venting ammonia to the atmosphere rather than converting the ammonia to urea or carbamate and urinating to dispose of excess salt, nitrogen, and water all at once, as normal animals are already set up to do?

Comment: @LoganR.Kearsley This chemical equation produces about 22.4 liters of ammonia at STP; even if it occurs over the course of a minute, that's about 1/3 of a liter per second. For reference, a human's lungs can hold about 6 liters of air at STP. Unless this critter can turn a mole of ammonia into a significantly less dense and therefore storable form within seconds, it's going to have to vent it. If you do have such a mechanism for it to do so, please let me know, because I've considered everything from converting it to urea to converting it to carbamate to converting it to ammonia water.

Comment: @KEY_ABRADE But you said it only produces a mole of ammonia every 5 minutes. That's about 17 grams. Look here it is : ". . .  and a mole of ammonia. In other words, I only need a single mole each of lye and ammonium chloride to cool more than a minute's worth of pumped blood .  . . "

Comment: @Daron Reacting a mole of lye, a mole of sal ammoniac, and 30.56 kilojoules of energy outputs 1 mole of ammonia gas, 1 mole of liquid water, and 1 mole of solid salt. At standard temperature and pressure (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standard_temperature_and_pressure), 1 mole of ammonia takes up 22.4 liters of space. If the reaction happens over the course of a minute, it outputs 22.4 liters/60 seconds = about 1/3 of a liter per second.

Comment: @KEY_ABRADE Okay 1 mole of ammonia weighs 17 grams. But it is a gas with volume 24 litres. You are using litre as a measure of volume and not weight -- duh!

Comment: @KEY_ABRADE In that case I suggest you chemically combine the ammonia with something else to make it a liquid or dissolved solid and take up less space. Of course you need a less energetic reaction than the original ammonium sal + lye reaction to avoid heating back up.

Comment: If your goal is to offset overheating (presumably from muscular exertion), then it's *much* more practical to draw the cooling process out by controlling the rate of your endothermic reaction - you suck out the same amount of heat/energy, but over a longer time, meaning your blood never goes cold enough to impair functionality **and** you can control the timing of the cooling effect more precisely **and** you have time to vent some waste products **and** I suspect the reaction is more efficient.

Comment: Note: biologically it would only want to offset increased heat production thus it should be whatever its normal body temperature is, otherwise it is impeding its own metabolism.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Ten Celsius**

[image]

Lizards are cold blooded and can survive as low as 10C. For comparison a pitiful human will simply stop working if the internal temperature goes outside the 35C - 40C range for too long.

The lizard is  not happy at this low temperature. In fact it can barely move. But its blood certainly still works as blood, evidenced by how the animal is not dead.

Your creature can survive at 10C if you make it more lizardy.

Answer (score 3):

## Within a degree of absolute zero.

There are many species of fish that survive in the sea below 0 C, the normal freezing point of water.  Frogs and turtles can freeze solid during the winter.  With the right antifreeze proteins, or other tricks like glycerol or trehalose, you humans' blood could be comparably resistant.  [See this paper](https://pubmed.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/7253609/) for human blood cooled to below 1 K with less than 1% hemolysis.

Freezing blood entirely, of course, interferes with respiration and related activities.  But many biological samples are kept liquid in glycerol at -80 degrees C.  Glycerol would be viscous, but I doubt your organism is moving too fast at those temperatures anyway.

Comment: Would it keep working to transport oxigen via hemoglobine, or is the substance just preserved, kept intact ? This opening is about a life, functioning and moving animal.

Comment: Chilled blood [can](https://www.mayoclinic.org/diseases-conditions/cryoglobulinemia/symptoms-causes/syc-20371244) be subject to special difficulties, and almost any blood will have slower gas diffusion in the cold.  But so long as it can be maintained liquid, *some* oxygen should be transportable by it.  The question suggests freezing and reheating is also allowable, and indicates the creature can reheat itself by some means.