# Altering the muscles of giant creatures to let them stand without collapsing by changing their proteins

Tags: internal-consistency, biology, chemistry, biochemistry, bio-mechanics

One of the problems with [scaling up creatures](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/109716/how-can-we-scale-up-living-creatures-to-be-giant-sized) without increasing their proportions is that their muscles won't be strong enough to support their weight due to [the square-cube law](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Square%E2%80%93cube_law), which I'm sure you're all familiar with. Muscles produce [20-135](http://downloads.lww.com/wolterskluwer_vitalstream_com/sample-content/9780781774222_Oatis/samples/Oatis_CH04_045-068.pdf) (see page 8) or [30-40](https://www.sciencelearn.org.nz/resources/1916-muscle-performance) newtons per square centimeter, or [4-8 kilograms force per square centimeter](https://www.hoddereducation.co.uk/media/Documents/magazine-extras/PE%20Review/PE%20Rev%20Vol%209%20No%201/PERev9_1_Strength-revision.pdf?ext=.pdf) (see page 2); this is (unfortunately for worldbuilding purposes) a limit.

One solution is to add more muscles in proportion to body mass. However, I don't like that solution; if I'm making a giant cat, I'd rather have a cat-shaped giant cat and not an elephant-shaped giant cat.

Another solution is to make the creature less dense. However, I don't like that solution either; it doesn't work particularly well when you're working with *really* giant creatures who'd still be incredibly massive even if filled with helium and structural voids.

I believe *my* solution is better than those two (of course; it's mine, after all). *My* solution is to make *the muscles themselves* stronger, and then to put said super-muscles into super-large-but-still-proportionate creatures in worldbuilding settings so they can exert enough force to function. To explain how I wish to implement this, a brief crash course in how muscles work is necessary.

---

### Image 1

[image]

This is a not-to-scale cross-section of the smallest functional unit of a [muscle cell](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Muscle_cell) - i.e. the point at which smaller structures are no longer identifiable as being part of a muscle, simply as being proteins.

Relevant things here are:

- The [thin filament](https://www.sciencedirect.com/topics/medicine-and-dentistry/thin-filament): the [helical](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Helix) thing on the top. It's made of all the things below that aren't the thick filament or myosin.
- The [thick filament](https://www.sciencedirect.com/topics/engineering/thick-filament): the pile-shaped thing on the bottom. All it's made of, functionally speaking, is myosin.
- [Tropomyosin](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tropomyosin) (green wavy lines): bonded to the actin, these are to troponin as a zip line is to a person riding it. As far as I know, it doesn't really serve a purpose other than being structural material, although there are [some theories that tropomyosin is what's responsible for myosin attaching to actin](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tropomyosin#Function_in_skeletal_muscle_contraction).
- [Myosin](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Myosin) (specifically, [myosin II/conventional myosin](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Myosin#Myosin_classes); shaped like an orange boxing glove): tries to stick to the actin above it if given a chance to do so.
- [Actin](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Actin) (unlabeled blue circles): what the myosin sticks to when given a chance. Bonded to the tropomyosin.
- [Troponin](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Troponin) (red circles): stops the myosin from sticking to the actin unless bribed with calcium (more on that later). While it's labeled "troponin" here, as if it were one protein, it's actually a [protein complex](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Protein_complex) made of [troponin C](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Troponin_C), [troponin I](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Troponin_I), and [troponin T](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Troponin_T) (more on that later too).

---

I would go over the entirety of the process by which a muscle contracts, but much of that'd be irrelevant for the purposes of this question. All you need to know is that:

1. I'm not going over *why* all the Ca2+ gets pumped into the cytoplasm; that's more related to the nervous system, and not relevant to this question.
2. When a muscle contracts, lots of [Ca2+](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Calcium_in_biology) (1 Ca2+ is a single [calcium](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Calcium) atom with a positive charge of 2 extra electrons) [ions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ion) get [pumped](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Voltage-gated_calcium_channel) into the [cytoplasm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cytoplasm) of that muscle's muscle cells.
3. Those Ca2+ ions stick to the [troponin C](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Troponin_C) in the muscles - remember that bit about troponin being "bribed" with calcium? This is that bit. Troponin C - again, remember that bit about troponin being made out of separate sub-parts? - is connected to [troponin I](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Troponin_I). Troponin I covers the slot where myosin can attach to actin, and, when Ca2+ ions stick to troponin C, the *entire* piece of troponin gets twisted - C, I, T, and all. That twisting pulls the tropinin I away from the slot where myosin can attach to actin (troponin T is just there to connect itself and the other 2 troponins to the tropomyosin, and serves a minimal part in this process).
4. Once the troponin I has been pulled away from the actin, the myosin takes advantage of the troponin I's absence and attaches to the actin, producing force and moving the muscle.
5. I'm not going through *how* the muscle un-contracts; what's relevant to this question is that all force exerted by muscles is caused by myosin attaching to actin.

This process is visualized in a semi-comprehensible and again not-to-scale fashion below:

### Image 2

[image]

---

What I wish to do is to attach more [myosin heads](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Myosin_head) (the club-shaped or boxing glove-shaped things) to the end of the first myosin head, as well as to add more myosin-to-actin attachment points to the thin filament so that those extra myosin heads have something to stick to. This is visualized in a semi-comprehensible, yet-again not to scale, poorly-Photoshopped fashion below:

### Image 3

[image]

---

Why would I do this? Well, it stands to reason that, since myosin heads attaching to attachment points on actin are what makes a muscle exert force, *more* myosin heads attaching to *more* attachment points on actin will make the muscle exert *more* force.

Now, of course, the extra force this generates will necessitate mechanically stronger muscles, but I believe spider silk or a similarly strong [protein](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Protein)-based material can cover for that, and I've [already worked around any heat-generation problems](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/230976/my-creatures-cells-mix-water-and-some-of-the-stuff-in-pee-to-cool-themselves-h) this might cause. I haven't troubleshot the metabolism-related issues (energy, [ATP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adenosine_triphosphate), and oxygen supply to these super-muscles) yet, and those will likely be insurmountable. I also have to deal with the bones of a super-large creature, which is also not quite done yet.

However, I'm not really here to get a solution to *those* problems; **I'm here to ask whether or not something like Image 3 is possible via any means - for instance, and I'm just spitballing here:**

- grafting more myosin heads onto pre-existing ones to increase the number of myosin/actin pairings
- having the body fabricate a new myosin-esque protein with multiple heads to increase the number of whatever-this-new-protein-is/actin pairings
- modifying myosin II so it grows multiple myosin heads, thereby increasing the number of myosin/actin pairings
- altering the structure of actin so it has more places for myosin to attach
- altering the structure of troponin T, so it can attach to *two* troponin C/troponin I pairs, as opposed to one, letting it cover two myosin/actin attachment spots at once, rather than one
- simply adding more troponin - again, so that more myosin/actin attachment spots can be covered while inactive

**The things on this list are just ideas, not questions I'm asking about - I'm aware of the single-question policy - but I'd really like to get more attachment points on these muscles, these might be ways to do that, and throwing my brainstorming at other people might help them come up with a solution.**

Comment: You could start by trying to find if some animals have denser or more efficient muscles than others, and what the microscopic differences are.

Comment: You also need stronger *bones*. But, frame challenge -- do you really *need* to delve in such details? I'd have thought you could go with, "differently structured proteins" and leave it at that. You'll never come up with a biologically feasible and efficient workaround, because if you could, chances are that it would already exist: the same mechanism would make normal-sized muscles way more efficient, allowing for *smaller* muscles and less energy expenditure - which, evolution-wise, would be desirable.

Comment: @LSerni arguably more bone is more important than more muscle.

Comment: The square cube law is a multi-layered killjoy that usually gets worse the bigger you go. You're growing too big? Your muscles can't keep up with the added weight. Your muscles can keep up now? Sure but not your bones, go take a seat. What's that? They can? Well I hope your neurons can travel fast enough so you don't need a minute to find out someone stabbed your foot, and also that your tissues have strong enough connections as to not to be stripped from your bones by gravity. And then there's the other killjoy known as thermodynamics, who comes after you whether you go big or small.

Comment: @LSerni As I said, I'm working on stronger bones. Also, note that evolution doesn't select for the optimal solution; it selects for the fittest solution within a local niche.

Comment: @ProjectApex I've already dealt with some of those problems; I don't really see how they're pertinent to this question.

Comment: My comment is much more of a rant than anything else. As for the question itself, I'm yet to find anything about such an arrangement at all, be It something natural or genetically engineered (congratulations, you might be up to a truly original concept). One thing that I'll say however is that, again, the natural laws of our universe don't take kindly to realistic attempts at colossal creatures. You'll ultimately be limited to how much the inter and intramolecular bonds of the proteins can endure before they break, which is equally true for spider silk. Sorry I can't seem to help for now.

Comment: VTC: (a) The [help/dont-ask] states, "To prevent your question from being flagged and possibly removed, avoid asking subjective questions where there is no actual problem to be solved." Compare this to [help/on-topic], "Worldbuilding Stack Exchange is a site ... to get help creating imaginary worlds." Whether or not a worldbuilding justification can work in the Real World isn't what we do. In short: you have a solution and needn't our permission to use it.

Comment: What exactly is your question ?

Answer (score 2):

You can't get there from here.

You can always make muscles stronger by adding more muscles. When muscles fail, it's the actual fibers that break, not the connection point, so adding more connection points would just make the muscle fibers break earlier. If you replace the myosin with spider silk, then you're discarding its regenerative capabilities. If you come up with a stronger form of myosin (in which case you're making up your own rules, and the answer becomes completely subjective) then you tear ligaments instead. This is the known limitation for bodybuilders who abuse steroids. If you magically strengthen the ligaments, then the bones break.

What you're describing is a quick patch to a complicated system that has been balanced by millennia of natural selection. If you're going to do that, you need to put in a LOT more research into the prior art. You can't just add more X like you're putting more cylinders into an internal combustion engine. That wouldn't work on an internal combustion engine, either. The drive train would get shredded.

Comment: Well, I already have solutions for the ligaments, the bones, the bodily cooling required to handle the increased heat more powerful muscles produce, and the synovial fluid in the joints (what some people forget). I worked backwards from making those structures more durable to this; this is just the last step.

Comment: I have a hard time believing that you've done anything more than apply patches to known shortfalls. If you're just shooting for "believable," then you are far exceeding "absorbable" for anyone that doesn't have a medical background. You've already lost the majority of the people who participate in this forum, and they're making an effort. What are you trying to accomplish with this information? Are you trying to build a real creature in real life? Are you trying to build a believable story? How do you expect this information to benefit you?

Comment: i'm just interested in it, really

Comment: +1. That's a much better way to put it than my comment. Thanks a lot.

Comment: @KEY_ABRADE, Without an objective on your part, it is impossible for us to answer your question. I suggest you ask on a medical information forum.